# all the index content is 403 forbidden

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

I downloaded the website template, the php is running fine but when I want to edit it, the contents of all indexes are 403 forbidden

[image: 1]

I tried to change the content or images on the website but I couldn't. does anyone know the solution?

Comment: Notice the huge difference in question quality between your question and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75786665/2943403)

Comment: please, provide more information, and code in text, not screenshots.